# 10 elements in 10 by 10 grid, no two in the same row or column

Tags: combinatorics

I have 10 elements that need to be arranged in a 10 by 10 grid such that no two elements occupy the same row or column.

I know the two diagonals work, and from looking at a smaller 3 by 3 grid I can find at least two other arrangements that fulfill these requirements. But I'm trying to find a general rule for this.

edit: how would this be different if they were indistinguishable vs distinct

Comment: Are the elements distinguishable?

Comment: These are the [involution numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_number_(mathematics))

Comment: no they are not does it matter?

Comment: @Sal don't think these are the involution numbers -- that would require the arrangement to be symmetric in the diagonal, which isn't necessarily the case here. Both Henry and Robert Israel's responses indicate that there is a much simpler formula here...

Comment: @jlammy Yes. I shouldn't have assumed the grid has any symmetries. Even if it did, I was still incorrect since those numbers are only *related* to the involution numbers.

Comment: after looking at other stuff I think I got it:

$\frac{12^2 * 11^2 * 10^2 * ... * 1^2}{12!}$

This uses the multiplication rule and all. Is it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

- You have $10$ elements to go into $10$ rows so one in each row
- Similarly with the columns

so

- Put one element in the first column in any of the $10$ rows
- Put one element in the second column in any of the $9$ free rows
- and so on with the rest of the elements and columns and remaining rows
- until you put the last element in the last column in the last remaining row

How many ways in total can you do this?

Comment: $10!$? Is it that simple?

Comment: edit: never mind see comment

Comment: @hhhiuw $10!$ is that simple.

Comment: @Henry So the answer is $\Pi_{i=1}^{10} i!$, right? I got confused.

Comment: No: if the elements are indistinguishable it is $10!$ $(3!=6$ if you had $3$ elements and a $3\times 3$ grid$)$, while if they are distinguishable it is $(10!)^2$.

Comment: Oh I thought there were $n^2$ elements in all ($n$ copies of each, so a latin square), but here are only $n=10$ elements. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Put them in $(i, p(i))$ for $i = 1 \ldots 10$ where $p$ is any permutation of $1,\ldots,10$.

Comment: Can you expand on what this means exactly? Is $(i, p(i))$ a coordinate? Would I use the multiplication rule to find the total number of possible coordinates?

Comment: $i$ is the row, $p(i)$ the column.  Do you know how many permutations of $1,\ldots,10$ there are?